# Задача по с++, связанная с квадратной матрицей

Tags: c++, матрицы

Помогите решить задачку)) Не понимаю что происходит. Определить значения которые будут содержаться во всех элементах матрицы, после выполнения следующего фрагмента. Нужна полная программа и что произойдёт в итоге. Вобщем дана квадратная матрица 3х3 заполненная единицами выглядящая следующий образом:

```
   1 2 3
   -----
1 |1 1 1
2 |1 1 1
3 |1 1 1
```

Программа: (То что заполнено многоточиями, необходимо заполнить какой-либо функцией)

```
int s,i,j;
int a[3][3];
...
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    s = 0;
    for(j = 3; j > 3; j--)
    {
        s = s + a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = s;
    }
} 
...
```

Comment: `for (j = 2; j >= 0; j--)`

Comment: @Igor У Вас нет чувства дежавю?

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup - *It's a glitch in the Matrix.*

Answer (score 0):

```
for (j = 2; j >= 0; j--)
```

---

```
3 2 1
3 2 1
3 2 1
```